# Where should I put code for a login/register form to be the most secure?

Tags: php, html, security

I am creating a user login/register form, and got OCD about it's security.

Which is safer from hackers and malicious code injectors? To place the code above the HTML (within the login form) like:

```php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

or write it in a separate PHP form like:

```html
<form action="sign_in.php" method = "post">
```

or another method entirely?

Comment: No difference. Worry about the weaknesses in your code rather than where you put it.

Comment: @JakeGould Hey you're right man. Just still a newbie here and got scared if my login site could be touched by the wrong hands. Thanks man.

Comment: You've got a lot of learning to do... (no offense);                I recommend reading OWASP.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am creating a user login/register form and got OCD about it’s
>   security. Which is safer from hackers and malicious code injectors? To
>   place the code above the HTML (within the login form) or write it in a
>   separate PHP form.

I commented above, but where you place the code has little to do with security. All of the PHP will be parsed by the PHP module in Apache (I assume) when the page is called & rendered.  So it could be spread into 1/2 a dozen files but it is still all sucked into one page for output.

So as far as security goes, there is no way your PHP code would be hacked by simple placement of backend code. That is not how hacks work or how flaws are exposed.

The more important thing is to simply make sure all user input is validated. And looking at your code, whatever you do you should NEVER pass along `$_POST` values without filtering, processing & validating them first.

If you plan on using PHP with MySQL, then you need to make sure you using [`mysqli_*` extensions with prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent MySQL injection. Because MySQL injection is the number one way sites are hacked nowadays.

Comment: thanks again man! I use `mysqli_connect` and stuffs... I'm also using `$name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);` is that safe enough?